# Как в одном html файле совместить несколько страниц?

Tags: скрипт, html

Пожалуйста, дайте скрипт.

Comment: вообще есть фреймы,но их использование не рекомендуется.

Comment: А какой фрейм надо использовать?

Comment: Фреймы - области, в которые загружаются независимые страницы. Если обычную страницу Вы размечаете как будут располагаться элементы, то тут определяете области, в которые загружаются страницы.

Comment: Почитайте http://htmlbook.ru/html/frame и http://htmlbook.ru/html/frameset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну можно еще на php.

```
<?
//если гет пустой, вставляем индех.пхп
if (!$_GET) {
    include('index.php');
    //Если page=any вставляем any.php
} elseif ($_GET[page] == any) {
    include('any.php');
}
?>
```

Вызов: первая страница будет грузиться по умолчанию, вторая к примеру: filename.php?page=any

Answer (score 3):

почитайте про jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

простой пример:

```
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>//путь до jQuery
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready(
        function()
        {
            $('#container').load('ajax/test.html');//страница, которая загрузится в div
        })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">//div, в который страница загрузится
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Не усел накатать) Имхо лучший вариант!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>  
 <head>
 <title>Хождение по фреймам</title>
</head>
 <frameset rows="100,*,150">
<frame src="logo.html">
 <frame src="content.html">
 <frame src="menu.html">
 </frameset>
 </html>
```

Comment: как код выделять при ответе?

Comment: [Синтаксис разметки][1]. Для того, чтобы отформатировать код выделите его и нажмите кнопку "101010", расположенную над редактором. Либо вставьте по 4 пробела перед каждой строкой кода вручную. 


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/markdown_help/

Comment: 1. Выделите ваш код и нажмите на пиктограмму с единицами и нулями
 2. Символами ``(в комментариях, например)
 3. Тегом pre

Comment: благодарствую)